# 2 equations for 2 variables with trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

2 equations for 2 variables

$x$ and $t$ are unknowns

$a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $f$, $g$ are constants

$$a+\left(8(t+b)+\frac{b^2}2-32\right)\sin(c)=d+et\sin(x)$$
$$f+\left(8(t+b)+\frac{b^2}2-32\right)\cos(c)=g+et\cos(x)$$

Solve for $x$ and $t$.

I've tried to change $\sin(x)$ to $\sqrt{1-cos^2(x)}$

Comment: hint : it is $\sin(x)=\pm \sqrt{1-\cos(x)^2}$

Comment: Should the final term be $et\cos(x)$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thanks

Comment: @Michael yes, it should be et*cos(x)

Answer (score 0):

solving the first equation for $t$ we obtain
$t=-1/2\,{\frac {\sin \left( c \right) {b}^{2}+16\,\sin \left( c \right) 
b-64\,\sin \left( c \right) +2\,a-2\,d}{-e\sin \left( x \right) +8\,
\sin \left( c \right) }}
$
and now we must insert this in the second equation but this need time to solve the new equation for $x$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

May be, the trick could be to define another variable $$y=8(t+b)+\frac{b^2}2-32$$ So, the equations become $$a+y\sin(c)=d+et\sin(x)$$ $$f+y\cos(c)=g+et\cos(x)$$ Isolate $\sin(x)$ from the first and $\cos(x)$ from the second and use $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$. This gives $$\frac{(a+y \sin (c)-d)^2+(y \cos (c)+f-g)^2}{e^2 t^2}=1$$ So, after expansion and simplifications, you end with $$2 y (a-d) \sin (c)+(a-d)^2+2 y \cos (c) (f-g)+(f-g)^2+y^2=e^2t^2$$ Plug now the expression of $y$ and you should arrive to something as $$A+Bt+Ct^2=0$$ with $$A=\left(b^2+16 b-64\right) (a-d) \sin (c)+(a-d)^2+\frac{b^4}{4}+8 b^3+\left(b^2+16
   b-64\right) \cos (c) (f-g)+32 b^2-512 b+(f-g)^2+1024$$ $$B=16 (a-d) \sin (c)+8 b^2+128 b+16 \cos (c) (f-g)-512$$ $$C=64-e^2$$ Solve it for $t$ and use one of the equations to get $\sin(x)$ and then $x$.

I hope and wish I did not make any mistake in these developments.